# Recursively calculate a list average

Tags: recursion, ocaml, average

I have homework to do in OCaml, and one question is about calculating the average of a list.
I did that already 1 or 2 years ago in another language, and as I did the first time, I decided to not only sum all elements and divide by the length. The main reason is the fear of a floating-point overflow.

So I found the formula I used the last time on Wikipedia : [recursive average formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Mba.png).

I coded it this way in OCaml :

```
let average = function
| []    -> raise Empty_list
| hd::l ->
    let rec aux average count = function
        | hd::l -> aux ((average*.(float (count-1))+.hd)/.(float (count))) (count+1) l
        | _     -> average
    in aux hd 1 l
;;
```

which for me looks like the exact transcription of the formula in OCaml.

But it didn't work, however, after taking a paper, a pen and thinking about it I managed to get it working by replacing the line:

`| hd::l  -> aux ((average*.(float (count-1))+.hd)/.(float (count))) (count+1) l`

with:

```
| hd::l -> aux ((average*.(float (count))+.hd)/.(float (count+1))) (count+1) l
```

and it worked.

I told myself the second line is logically the good one to compute the right answer, but I can't understand what was wrong in the first place. Did I translate a biased formula? Or did I miss something when translating?

At this point, it still looks for me like the first line is the transcription of the formula, and the second line is the way to compute the right answer. But I believe there's something I can't understand here. May someone shed light on this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the formula but in the way you use it.

You call `aux hd 1 l`. So you start with an average of the head of the list and a count of 1. But in the formula you multiply the previous average with `count - 1`, which is 0 on the first call. So what you do is throw away the head.

Written that way the way to call it is `aux 0.0 1 (hd::tl)` or `aux hd 2 tl`.

If you further allow that the average of an empty list is 0.0 you don't even need a pattern matching for the outer function. Going one step further if you make the average and count arguments optional (default to 0.0 and 1 respectively) you don't even need a helper function:

```
let rec average ?(avg=0.0) ?(count=1) = function
| []     -> avg
| hd::tl -> average
                ~avg:((avg*.(float (count-1))+.hd)/.(float (count)))
                ~count:(count+1)
                tl;;
val average : ?avg:float -> ?count:int -> float list -> float = <fun>

# average [1.;2.;3.];;
- : float = 2.
```

Comment: "But in the formula, you multiply the previous average with count - 1".  That's true, I'm doing this but isn't it what the formula tells? I guess something is wrong in my thought process: The formula is defined for n=1 otherwise, it wouldn't be recursive. The mean x for n(=1)-1 is x0 and is multiplied by n(=1)-1, so 0. So yes, we're losing the first value... I thought the same on paper with a pen. I stupidly tagged my question as Ocaml but I hardly believe it's more about Wikipedia or me and mathematics. I think it's the second option.

Comment: In the formula the count is supposed to be the count of the current item. You removed the head of the list (item 1) so when you use the formula the next item should have count 2. But you have 1. You are off-by-1.

Comment: I had no problem to see why my code wasn't working. It just seemed contradictory with this formula on Wikipedia. Now I better understand what the formula means but it still seams strange to me. On french wiki it says the n is "the count of consecutive values", they call it "period" too. But it still looks to me as the mean of 0 consecutive values is nothing; not the first one of the list. It's litterally written next to the starting case "A moving average of period 0 takes only one term". Shouldn't the moving average of  one consecutive term be only one term instead ?

Comment: Wikipedia can be wrong too. The formula only works if the first item has a count of 1 and the second item a count of 2 and so on. If your indexes are supposed to be 0 based then you have to use `count` and `count+1` in the formula instead. Note my use of *index* there. Most often indexes are 0 based but a *count*, size or length would be 1 based. A period of 0 should pair with a count of 1 imho.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is a version of the function that does not overflow with the right time complexity:

```ml
let avg l =
  let mu_n' (n,mu_n) x =
    let n' = n + 1 in
    n', mu_n +. (x -. mu_n) /. float n' in
  snd (List.fold_left mu_n' (0,0.) l)

let x = avg [max_float; 1.; 2.; max_float;2.; 3.; max_float; 5.; 6.]
let relative_error = (x -. max_float /. 3.) /. (max_float /. 3.)
```

> val relative_error : float = -1.66533453693773481e-16

Answer (score 1):

> But I believe there's something I can't understand here

Nothing is wrong with your logic in general, the formula itself is the source of confusion, I think.

It is quite obvious that `(n - 1)` multiplier in the dividend must NOT turn into zero during the calculation (otherwise you "discard" the previously accumulated value - which actually happened with your first attempt), and the only way to ensure this is to set `n > 0`. So, the first equation (the default case) must be indexed by 1, not 0.

So, you have n = 1 for the base case, n = 2 for the next iteration etc. which matches your second (correct) expression and not the first one...

Comment: You are confirming what I thought. One left question is: does that mean the formula is "wrong"? Should it be corrected to have the base case something like û1 = u1? I don't know how to write mathematical stuff here but I think you'll see what I mean. Or maybe base case should be split into two cases where index=0 and index=1?

Comment: Yes, the formula seems to be wrong. It's quite typical to have base case indexed with 0 for math. induction, but it's not the requirement. And in this particular case the formula is correct only if `n` starts with 1...

Answer (score 1):

There's a cleaner form of the formula for average which finds the delta between the old average and the new observation, then scales the delta by the sample size to update the average.  The base case is that the average of a single observation is that observation.  (The average of an empty list is undefined.)

In OCaml:

```
let rec avg lst =
  match lst with
    | [x]     -> x
    | x::rest -> avg rest +. (x -. avg rest) /. float(List.length lst)
    | []      -> failwith "avg called on empty list!"
;;
```

The recursive call should only evaluate once since it is pure.

Comment: You don't want to use `List.length` here, that makes the function quadratic in the list length. And the recursive call is evaluated twice, making the function exponential in the length of the list.

Comment: @octachron I'm an occasional OCaml user (3 times in a decade), so if there's a better way to use the size of the list I'm all ears.  That said, the documentation I reviewed said that if OCaml can detect that nothing has changed between two invocations of a function, it's considered "pure", will only be evaluated the first time, and the result will be retained for use in subsequent evaluation.

Comment: OCaml don't track purity at the function level. More generally, relying on a compiler optimization to change the complexity of an algorithm is always brittle. And in this case, even with `-O3`, your function is not optimized. Let me write the right function.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it so complicated? Why not just calculate the sum and count?

```
let int_avg lst =
  let rec int_avg_aux cnt sum lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> (cnt, sum)
    | hd::tl -> int_avg_aux (cnt + 1) (hd + sum) tl in
  int_avg_aux 0 0 lst

let (c, s) = int_avg [1;2;3;4;5;]

let () = Printf.printf "%d %d\n" c s
```

Now you have the number of elements and the sum of the elements.

Comment: Well, there are two things, first, it must be applied to floating-point lists, even though the algorithm is the same. On the other hand and to answer your question, I'm using this method to avoid having an overflow of the `sum` variable. The `count` variable can overflow too but I don't meet Int.max_int-sized lists every day.

Comment: Your recursive function still overflows when computing `count * average`.

Comment: @octachron See my answer for a variant which avoids that overflowing calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your formula in OCaml and I think I got it right:

```
let avg c lst =
  let rec avg_aux c l =
  match l with
  | [] -> 0.0
  | hd::tl ->
    (((avg_aux (c -. 1.0) tl) *. (c -. 1.0)) +. hd) /. c in
  avg_aux c lst

let lst = [max_float;2.0;max_float;4.0;5.0;6.0]

let ans = avg (float(List.length lst)) lst

let () = Printf.printf "%f\n" ans
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Why provide two answers? Do you really think this question deserves two separate anwers?

Comment: @G4143 I'm not really looking for code; substituting the original line with the modified one makes the function work perfectly. What I can't get is the first line seems to be the "translation" of the mathematical formula in OCaml, when the modified one doesn't seem to. So either there's something I miss in the formula, and its translation is my modified line; either the formula is wrong... (what I can't really believe). I admit the question is more maths-related than OCaml-related. Also, I'm grateful for the attention you're paying to my question.